# Query where a Parent a child with a particular property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a Parent that has_many :children

I want to pull out all the Parents that don't have a child with favourite set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have a terminal but can you try this?:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children

  scope :evil, select("parents.*, SUM(children.favourite) as fav_count").joins("LEFT JOIN children ON (children.parent_id = parents.id AND children.favourite = 1)").group("parents.id").having("fav_count = 0")
end
```

I'd love for a cleaner syntax but I'm not sure of a better approach (anyone)?  Let me know if there's any SQL errors but I **think** that will give you what you need.

**NOTE**: to use this you'd simply go `Parent.evil` or you can chain it on an association `foo.parents.evil`

Comment: how do I use that scope in my controller?

Comment: but now it's coming up with this `misuse of aggregate: COUNT()`

Comment: `@parents = Parent.evil` (or whatever you need to call it).  Scopes always work on a collection of parents and return a scoped set of them.  They can be chained together, for example `Parent.evil.brown_hair.blue_eyes` if you had `brown_hair` and `blue_eyes` scopes.

Comment: @Joseph, please use `.having()` instead of `.where()` in the last part of your scope

Comment: Yeah it's this `SQLite3::SQLException: misuse of aggregate: COUNT(): SELECT parents.*, COUNT(*) as a_count FROM "parents" LEFT JOIN children ON children.parent_id = children.id WHERE (a_count = 0) GROUP BY parents.id`

Comment: My mistake, you'll need to change it to a HAVING clause.  HAVING is used to evaluate conditions on AGGREGATEs from your GROUP BY (in this case, COUNT() is your aggregate)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3244/discussion-between-kristian-pd-and-joseph-le-brech)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with a simple join using ActiveRecord:

```
Parent.where(:children => {:favourite => true}).joins(:children)
```

Comment: i want to retrieve parents that do not have a favourite child.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent.joins(:children).where(children:{favorite:true})
```

Note I am using the 1.9 hash syntax which I think looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: a parent may have a a child that is not favourite along with a favourite tho.